# What is the difference between "/wps/portal" and "/wps/myportal" in IBM WebSphere Portal?

Tags: java, portal, websphere-portal

I'm using IBM WebSphere Portal, and what is the difference between `/wps/portal` and `/wps/myportal` in IBM WebSphere Portal?

Answer (score 6):

`/wps/portal` is for anonymous context and is used for public resources, whereas `/wps/myportal` is used for authenticated and authorized resources.

Comment: It's also worth noting that, in the OOTB configuration, navigating to /wps/portal when you're logged in will log you out.